# CodeIgniter Controller- How do I pass status back to calling function

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am posting some data to an action on a controller using the CI framework. The post completed successfully but I would like to return a status to the calling jQuery.post().

Using firebug I can see that the post is completed successfully (200) but I don't see the json that I am returning. How come I am not getting the json returned?

```
public function sendMail()
{
    $senderName = trim($_POST['senderName']);
    $returnEmail = trim($_POST['returnEmail']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);


    if (valid_email($returnEmail))
    {
        send_email('me@my.com','Website Email From: '.$senderName, $message);
        $success = array('success'=>'Mail Sent');
        echo json_encode($success);
    }
    else
    {
        $errorMessage = array('error'=>'Invalid Email Address');
            echo json_encode($errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Ajax post

```
$.post("http://example.com/index.php/mail/sendmail",{senderName: senderName, returnEmail: senderAddr, message: message }, function(data){
if(data.status == "success")
{
    alert("mail sent.");
}
else
{
    alert("mail failure");
}
});
```

Comment: what's the output when you console.log(data);?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the url. I think trying to post to 'http://mysite.com' from my local host was causing cross site scripting security issues.

I changed the url property to something relative and it works great.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "index.php/mail/sendmail",
    data: {senderName: senderName, returnEmail: senderAddr, message: message},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data){
        if(typeof data.error == "undefined"){
            alert("Mail failure");
        }
        else{
            alert("Mail sent");
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("Something went wrong"); // possible that JSON wasn't returned
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test by using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` until you get the desired result. Your code should work unless:

- You haven't loaded the e-mail helper
- You're using an old PHP version which doesn't support `json_*()`
- Case sensitive method (`sendMail`, not `sendmail`)

I'd also recommend using the following code for your JavaScript as well:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://mysite.com/index.php/mail/sendmail",
    data: {senderName: senderName, returnEmail: senderAddr, message: message},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data){
        if(typeof data.error == "undefined"){
            alert("Mail failure");
        }
        else{
            alert("Mail sent");
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("Something went wrong"); // possible that JSON wasn't returned
    }
});
```

Comment: It does work.. I'm trying to get the response back to the client.

Comment: Also.. a GET does not allow you to pass data in the body of an HTTP request. A GET restricts you to passing data in the query string.

Comment: But.. I am going to try and just use the more verbose .ajax() Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I refactored to use the AJAX() and it appears that the error function is called even though the server response has a status of 200

Comment: The error function is also called when the returned format doesn't match the `dataType`. In this case `ajax()` is expecting that /index.php/mail/sendmail returns proper JSON.

Comment: That's interesting. I am encoding the array to json using PHP's json_encode(). I don't do much PHP so I will check and see if this step is somehow faulty. Thanks again.